# Problem to display data from actions and reducer - react native redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I almost done my application but at this moment i have problem with a actions and reducer.
So my app allows to check a currencies and their price. When I pick an item from Picker component value of price doe'snt change. It is all time default EUR -> PLN. Here is the example of usage

[image]

Firstly user can write price of EUR and next it converts to PLN -> result is ok with this configuration. But if I change configuration to USD -> PLN price doesn't change :(.

[image]

Another problem is when I choose on both picker's value "EUR" i have NaN

'1 EUR is equevalent to NaN EUR'

Also i notice that when i change bottom picker item then price converts. So to be clear: if is

EUR -> PLN = ok

USD -> PLN = price from previous configuration(whatever it is)

USD -> ALL = works

so definitly I think there is some problem with the upper Picker component. There is my code what I'm using to handle this.

action.js

```
export const handleFirstSelect = itemValue => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.HANDLE_FIRST_SELECT,
    itemValue: itemValue,
  };
};
```

reducer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  currencies: ['USD', 'AUD', 'SGD', 'PHP', 'EUR', 'PLN', 'GBP'],
  base: 'EUR',
  amount: '',
  convertTo: 'PLN',
  result: '',
  date: '',
  error: null,
  loading: false,
};

const exchangeCurrencies = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.HANDLE_FIRST_SELECT:
      return {
        ...state,
        base: action.itemValue,
      };
    case actionTypes.HANDLE_SECOND_SELECT:
      return {
        ...state,
        convertTo: action.itemValue,
      };
    case actionTypes.HANDLE_INPUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        amount: action.text,
        date: state.date,
      };
    case actionTypes.HANDLE_SWAP:
      return {
        ...state,
        convertTo: state.base,
        base: state.convertTo,
        e: action.e,
      };
    case actionTypes.FETCH_DATA_BEGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: null,
      };
    case actionTypes.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        result: action.data.rates,
        date: action.data.date,
      };
    case actionTypes.FETCH_DATA_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.error,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default exchangeCurrencies;
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thans for all answers. Of course I can add more code if its neccesery.

EDIT: also adding a component code

```
class HomeContentContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      base: 'EUR',
      amount: '',
      convertTo: 'PLN',
      result: '',
      date: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.amount === isNaN) {
      return;
    } else {
      try {
        this.props.fetchData();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        style={styles.imageBackground}
        source={require('../../assets/images/2.jpeg')}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.inputsContainer}>
            <TextInputComponent
              value={this.props.amount}
              onChangeText={this.props.handleInput}
            />
            <PickerComponent
              selectedValue={this.props.base}
              onValueChange={this.props.handleFirstSelect}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.inputsContainer}>
            <TextInputComponent
              editable={false}
              value={`${
                this.props.amount === ''
                  ? '0'
                  : this.props.result === null
                  ? 'Calculating...'
                  : this.props.result
              }`}
            />
            <PickerComponent
              selectedValue={this.props.convertTo}
              onValueChange={this.props.handleSecondSelect}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
        <ResultText
          equevalentText={`${this.props.amount} ${
            this.props.base
          } is equevalent to `}
          amountText={`${
            this.props.amount === ''
              ? '0'
              : this.props.result === null
              ? 'Calculating...'
              : this.props.result
          }${' '}${this.props.convertTo}`}
          dateText={`As of ${
            this.props.amount === ''
              ? ''
              : this.props.date === null
              ? ''
              : this.props.date
          }`}
        />
        <CustomButton onClick={this.props.handleSwap} buttonTitle="SWAP" />
        <BottomSignature />
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    base: state.base,
    amount: state.amount,
    convertTo: state.convertTo,
    result: (state.result[state.convertTo] * state.amount).toFixed(2),
    date: state.date,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    handleFirstSelect: itemValue => dispatch(exchangeCurriencesActions.handleFirstSelect(itemValue)),
    handleSecondSelect: itemValue => dispatch(exchangeCurriencesActions.handleSecondSelect(itemValue)),
    handleInput: text => dispatch(exchangeCurriencesActions.handleInput(text)),
    fetchData: () => dispatch(exchangeCurriencesActions.fetchData()),
    handleSwap: e => dispatch(exchangeCurriencesActions.handleSwap(e)),
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(HomeContentContainer);
```

Comment: it doesn't look like there is something wrong in your actions/reducer, it seems that there is something wrong with how you handle this changes in your view.

Comment: Do you mean component where I dispatching functions?

Comment: Yeah, i believe the actual bug is in the logic within the component.  the action and reducer are doing their work, which is actually updating the Redux Store data, what is wrong is that you are getting a NAN or the same price so it seems that you are not using this store data correctly, but is difficult to be sure without debbuging this logic.

Comment: I'll edit my post and write code for this component

Comment: (state.result[state.convertTo] * state.amount).toFixed(2) i believe this is the problem at least one of the problems you should parse those values to float before trying to do an operation, since amount and result seem to be strings at some times